# why class-based view returned type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'model'?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

i have a website with django.

this is the project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('accounts.urls')),
url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^register/$', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
url(r'^logout/$', logout_view, name="logout")
]
```

and this is the accounts.urls:

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'(?P<username>[\w]+)/$', views.Profile.as_view(), name='profile_cbv'),
]
```

and this is Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile', verbose_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='name')
    family = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='family')
```

and at last, this is the Profile class-based view:

```
class Profile(View):
def get(self, request, username=None):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)

    print(profile)
    pass
```

for example, i go to below url:

```
localhost:8000/ivan/
```

it raises below error:

```
AttributeError at /ivan/
type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'model'
```

if I pass a correct or an incorrect username with url to view, all the times, it raises that error.

what's the problem?

Comment: first you should rename the view called `Profile` into something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `get_object_or_404(Profile, ...)`, it takes `Profile` not as your **model**, but as your **view**. That's why you receive that error.

Try renaming `class Profile(View)` to `class ProfileView(View)`:

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'(?P<username>[\w]+)/$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_cbv'),
]
```

And in your `views.py`:

```
class ProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request, username=None):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)

        print(profile)
        pass
```

Comment: yeah, as you said, the problem was because name of model and view was same. thank you so much

Comment: @MojtabaSalehiyan You're welcome. If my answer helped you make sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a name issue in the views. Your view class name is the same as the model class. Import the Model class as something else. For example:

> from .models import Profile as ProfileModel

Then call the model that way in the view.